# Write an algorithm printing the removed element from head of a linked list in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, arraylist, linked-list

First of all this is an assignment. I'm not asking for any code just clarification.

I don't really understand the question, does it mean to put the removed element in an array and print it right away when you call the method removing the head element meaning every time I print 1 element and the array capacity is always 1? or you create an array as a class member and each time you remove an element it is put in the array and then have a method for printing the array? if so how do you deal with the array capacity since linked lists are not fixed sized?

My own solution is to create a static arraylist and each time I call deleteFirst() method, the data inside the node is put in the arraylist and then I just have a method printing the arraylist, to me this seems like a logical solution but I'm restricted to using arrays.

deleteFirst() deletes the head node in the linked list.

Comment: Would be good if you clarify it with your professor. To me it means just print deleted element but given "in an array" is bit confusing.

Comment: I asked her and she said you have to put every removed element from the head of the linked list in an array and that I have to put all the code in an method and just call it from main. @almas shaikh

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your assignment, you could do something like arrayList does with [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method:

```
 MyElementType[] elementArray = new MyElementType[10];
 .....
 element = deleteFirst();
 if (!doWeHaveEmptyLocationInArray()) {
       MyElementType[] tempElementArray = new MyElementType[elementArray.length() * 2];//double the size of array
       System.arraycopy(elementArray, 0, tempElementArray, 0, elementArray.lengh());//copy elements from old array to new one
       elementArray = tempElementArray;
 }
 ...add the removed element to new array
```

Comment: So I have to make an array that acts like an arraylist?

Comment: Yes as its your assignment i suggest array acting like an arrayList yes.